# Run AIY assistant demo from command line

Tags: environment, google-assistant-sdk

Everything works fine as long as I am using the special "developer" terminal on the desktop.  However, the desktop is incredibly slow and I want to just want to start it from an ssh command line but when I run

```
src/assistant_library_demo.py
```

I get

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "src/assistant_library_demo.py", line 30, in <module>
    import aiy.assistant.auth_helpers
  File "/home/pi/AIY-voice-kit-python/src/aiy/assistant/auth_helpers.py", line 24, in <module>
    import google_auth_oauthlib.flow
ImportError: No module named 'google_auth_oauthlib'`

Where is the magic script that sets-up the environment so that the examples work on a normal command line?

Comment: I have the same problem here. I wish I knew the answer. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

The script is located here: `~/bin/AIY-voice-kit-shell.sh`